# Using Entity Framework Transaction Correctly for Isolation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 and SQL Server 2016 for my ASP.Net Website. I recently found a problem with concurrency at one of my function. The function is used for processing unpaid order and sometimes this function is executed multiple times for the same key and the same time (because multiple user access it together).

Here is what it looks like.

```
public void PaidOrder(string paymentCode)
{
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction trans = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Order_Payment_Code payment = db.Order_Payment_Code.Where(item => item.PaymentCode == paymentCode).FirstOrDefault();
                if(payment.Status == PaymentStatus.NotPaid)
                {
                    //This Scope can be executed multiple times
                    payment.Status = PaymentStatus.Paid;
                    db.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    //Continue processing Order

                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why scope inside my `if` statement can be executed multiple time even it is inside a transaction? Isn't transaction suppose to be isolating the data? Or my understanding of transaction is wrong? If so, then what is the correct way to make the scope inside my `if` statement only executed once?

Comment: depends on several things: the isolation level of the transaction (by default it will be ReadCommitted), and what you do in that transaction.

Comment: @MitchWheat I didn't set any isolation level option, so I think it is the default. And what I do other than updating `PaymentStatus` above is basically insert and update some other table.

Comment: Your real problem is here "and sometimes this function is executed multiple times for the same key and the same time (because multiple user access it together)." Rather than lock the the table and block all other access, it would be better to fix the cause rather than the symptoms.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I think it's not possible because the page connected to this function is showing list of unpaid Order and a button to set the payment status to Paid. I can't prevent the button only clicked once because the page is accessed by multiple user. So I'm trying to block the table using transaction (at least even when the button is clicked multiple times, it only processed once at the first click). But unfortunately it's not run as expected.

Comment: At the very least you should implement optimistic concurrency.

Comment: The selection you have just before your `IF` statement will only ever place shared locks (**(S)**) on your rows in SQL Server - but those are compatible with other shared locks, which means **multiple** users / session could be selecting the **same data row** at the same time (and thus then execute the `IF` part separately, on the same data). Here, a transaction doesn't offer any help

Comment: @marc_s, yes, I think it is the case. So, how do I make it lock all other transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and reliable way to serialize an EF SQL Server transaction is to use an [Application Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Add this method to your DbContext:

```
public void GetAppLock(string lockName)
{
    var sql = "exec sp_getapplock @lockName, 'exclusive';";
    var pLockName = new SqlParameter("@lockName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
    pLockName.Value = lockName;
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, pLockName);
}
```

And call it just after you start your transaction.

```
public void PaidOrder(string paymentCode)
{
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction trans = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            db.GetAppLock("PaidOrder");
            Order_Payment_Code payment = db.Order_Payment_Code.Where(item => item.PaymentCode == paymentCode).FirstOrDefault();
            if(payment.Status == PaymentStatus.NotPaid)
            {
                //This Scope can be executed multiple times
                payment.Status = PaymentStatus.Paid;
                db.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                //Continue processing Order

            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Then only one instance of that transaction can run at a time, even if you have multiple front-end servers.  So this is like a Mutex that works across all the clients that access the same database.